# Gmail search messages within a time period

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I want to use google apps script to search messages within a time period. My current code looks like this:

```
let threads = GmailApp.search("newer_than:1h");
for (let i = 0; i < threads.length; ++i) {
  let messages = threads[i].getMessages();
  for (let ii = 0; ii < messages.length; ++ii) {
    foo(messages[ii]);
  }
}
```

The problem is that if a thread's latest message is received within 1 hour, all the messages in this thread will be returned. I know I can check the date of each message using `messages[ii].getDate()` to enforce each message called by `foo()` is within 1 hour. But is there any other way more direct to retrieve the messages within 1 hour? Is there an API similar to `GmailApp.search()` that works for messages?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Gmail API to achieve that:

1. [Active](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) the [advanced service of the Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail)
2. Use the method described in [Searching for Messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering)

Sample:

```js
function searchMsgs() {
  msgs = Gmail.Users.Messages.list("me",{
    q: "newer_than:1h"
  })
  console.log(msgs)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there anyway to read the message's content? This is the response I got from msgs:```{"messages":[{"threadId":"111111","id":"1111111"}],"resultSizeEstimate":1}```. I tried `msgs["messages"][0].getPayload()`, but it returns `undefined`.

Comment: As you can read in the GMAIL API documentation for `User.Messages.list` : `List of messages. Note that each message resource contains only an id and a threadId. Additional message details can be fetched using the messages.get method.`, in short, you can't read the message content from `list`, you need to loop it through and use `get`. Consider accepting/up-voting the answer if you consider it helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I ask where did you find the document of `Gmail.Users.Messages.list()`? I am trying to find document for `Gmail.Users.Messages.get()` but I can only find this [link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get). It only describes how to use the `get()` by a `GET` call. Is there any other document for using the `get()` natively like a function? Just like the way you use `Gmail.Users.Messages.list()`? Thanks