# can't decode gmail message returned by users.messages.get()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, base64, gmail, gmail-api

I am using Google Apps Script API [users.messages.get()](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22184e0f12b9c0b655%22%2C%22format%22%3A%22raw%22%7D) to read gmail message. I have a valid message id. Below is my code snippet:

```
let message = Gmail.Users.Messages.get("me", id);
let encodedBody = message["payload"]["parts"][0]["body"]["data"];
let body = Utilities.base64Decode(encodedBody);
```

Per the doc at this [link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22184e0f12b9c0b655%22%2C%22format%22%3A%22raw%22%7D), `encodedBody` should be a base64 encoded string, and when I use `Try this method` at this [page](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22184e0f12b9c0b655%22%2C%22format%22%3A%22raw%22%7D), it indeed return a base64 encoded string that can be decoded on this [website](https://www.base64decode.org/). However, when I run the google apps script, it throws this exception: `Exception: Could not decode string.`. Upon checking, the `encodedBody` looks like this when I print it in the goole apps script console:

```
[60,33,68,79,67,84,89,80,69,32,104,116,109...]
```

It's a huge array of integers instead of a base64 encoded string. May I ask why this happens? Can anyone provide a working example in google apps script to read the gmail message body? I can't use `GmailApp.search().getMessages()` for reasons mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73714487/gmail-search-messages-within-a-time-period).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your showing value of `[60,33,68,79,67,84,89,80,69,32,104,116,109...]` and if the value of `encodedBody` is `[60,33,68,79,67,84,89,80,69,32,104,116,109...]`, I thought that the value is the byte array of int8Array for Google Apps Script. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
let body = Utilities.base64Decode(encodedBody);
```

#### To:

```
let body = Utilities.newBlob(encodedBody).getDataAsString();
```

- By this modification, the text data is retrieved from the byte array.
- If the data is binary data, how about the following modification?

  ```
    let body = DriveApp.createFile(Utilities.newBlob(encodedBody));
  ```

  - By this, the data is created as a file to the root folder.

#### Note:

- If an error occurs, please check the value of `encodedBody` again.

#### Reference:

- [newBlob(data)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#newBlob(Byte))

Comment: So you can download the raw message and save it directly to drive?  What is the format of the file when it gets to drive?

Comment: @DaImTo Thank you for replying. About your question, if your value of `encodedBody` is `[60,33,68,79,67,84,89,80,69,32,104,116,109...]`, it is considered that the value is int8Array. At Gmail API of Advanced Google services, it seems that the value of int8Array is returned. When I tested it in my Gmail, `Utilities.newBlob(encodedBody).getDataAsString()` and `DriveApp.createFile(Utilities.newBlob(encodedBody))` work. And, if you want to confirm the mimeType of this value, you can see it at `["parts"][0]["mimeType"]` instead of `["parts"][0]["body"]["data"]`.

Comment: I have been trying to do something like this but im using thread.getMessages(),  getRawContent() getBody() getPlainBody()  all just return a string.   I was hoping to be able to turn this into a PDF.

Comment: @DaImTo In the case of `getBody()`, `getPlainBody()` and `getRawContent()` of Gmail service (GmailApp) which is not Gmail API, those return a string value. So, you can directly see it. And, if you want to create a PDF file from the HTML body, you can achieve it with `DriveApp.createFile(Utilities.newBlob(GmailApp.getMessageById(id).getBody(), MimeType.HTML, "sample.pdf").getAs(MimeType.PDF))`.

Comment: @DaImTo As additional information, in the case of Gmail API of Advanced Google services, the value of `raw` of `const {raw} = Gmail.Users.Messages.get("me", id, {format: "raw"})` is also the int8Array, while the value is base64 data in the case of "Try this method" of Gmail API.

Comment: Want me to open a new question?

Comment: Well that worked thank you its ugly but its a pdf :)

Comment: @DaImTo I think that this discussion is related to this question. So, it will be useful for not only OP but also other users. For example, if you have a different question from this question, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question. About the creation of the PDF file, I thought that there is no large difference even when the HTML is converted to PDF format with Drive API. I think that this method using `Utilities.newBlob` might be simpler.

Comment: @DaImTo I understand it. I can wait for

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74687988/1841839  Your the only one i know who could answer that :)

Comment: @DaImTo Thank you. I will check your question. When I can find a solution, I will post it. When I have a question, I will ask it.

Comment: @Hard Mode Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.