# App script with Domain wide delegation. and standard calendar service

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I have a script which works with Google domain wide delegation. To a service account on my Google workspace account.

This script allows me to access the calendar accounts of users on the domain.  The issue is that i have to use the Oauth2 library and make all calls directly to the api

But what i would like to do is go though the standard google calendar service that is part of app script [calendar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar)

My question is how can I get this service to use the delegation I have created?  It wants to be authorized to the account I am currently running when i try to use it and not use the delegated user I have authorized.

```
// Oauth script id 1B7FSrk5Zi6L1rSxxTDgDEUsPzlukDsi4KGuTMorsTQHhGBzBkMun4iDF


function run() {

  var email = '[Redacted]@daimto.com';  // a user to delegate to


  var service = getDomainWideDelegationService('Calendar: ', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', email);

  if (!service.hasAccess()) {

    Logger.log('failed to authenticate as user ' + email);      

  } else Logger.log('successfully authenticated as user ' + email);

   Logger.log('access token ' + service.getAccessToken())    

   getCalendar(service)

}



function getCalendar(service){


var requestBody                = {};
  requestBody.headers            = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()};
  requestBody.contentType        = "application/json";
  requestBody.method             = "GET";
  requestBody.muteHttpExceptions = false;  

  var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList/primary';

  var calendarGetResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestBody);


   Logger.log('response ' + calendarGetResponse)    

}

// these two things are included in the .JSON file that you download when creating the service account and service account key
var OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY = '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----[Redacted]END PRIVATE KEY-----';
var OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_EMAIL = 'workspace-testing@workspaceserviceaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com';



function getDomainWideDelegationService(serviceName, scope, email) {

  Logger.log('starting getDomainWideDelegationService for email: ' + email);

  return OAuth2.createService(serviceName + email)
    // Set the endpoint URL.
    .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')

    // Set the private key and issuer.
    .setPrivateKey(OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY)
    .setIssuer(OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_EMAIL)

    // Set the name of the user to impersonate. This will only work for
    // Google Apps for Work/EDU accounts whose admin has setup domain-wide
    // delegation:
    // https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority
    .setSubject(email)

    // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())

    // Set the scope. This must match one of the scopes configured during the
    // setup of domain-wide delegation.
    .setScope(scope);

}
```

I have an another version of this script that I am working on that keeps users gmail signatures updated wither they like it or not.

Comment: In your endpoint, `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList/primary` is used. In this case, I thought that it might be `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList`. How about this? About `But what i would like to do is go though the standard google calendar service that is part of app script calendar`, I think that when the access token is required to be used, it is required to directly request to the endpoint of API. In this case, I think that the Calendar API of Advanced Google services cannot be also used.

Comment: .setSubject(email)  is used for [delegation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/delegation) to a user on the google workspace domain.    These are service account credentials not standard Oauth2.

Comment: Yes. About `.setSubject(email)`, I noticed that I misunderstood your question. I understood that your question is to use Calendar service with the service account. So, I had modified my 1st comment.

Comment: I thought that in this case, this might be related to the situation that the Google Apps Script project on Google Drive of the service account cannot be used. I thought that if this can be used, your goal might be able to be achieved. But, there might be more information I have never known. So, also I would like to expect other user's comments.

Comment: Well yes this does work using a service account.   Is just harder to use then if we could use the standard calendar service with it.  Your average developer would find it harder to do this as you have to create the full request manually including the headers.    Its easer if we could do this using the standard services provided by app script.

Comment: Yes. In my experience, when I tested using Google Apps Script API and Web Apps (`Execute as: User accessing the web app` and `Who has access: Anyone with Google account`) with the service account, both patterns failed. From this result, I thought that this might be the current specification.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible. If you want the benefits of Domain-wide delegation (DwDg) you'll have to write your own Calendar API client. Given Google's strong push towards tighter data privacy controls in recent years, DwDg via service accounts might get the axe. So take advantage of it while you can.

Comment: For google workspace i dont think they will discontinue it.

Comment: @DaImTo Google has been rolling out new authorization strategies of late, such as Workload Identity Federation. It's not a substitute for all the scenarios a service account can cover, but it is touted as a more secure substitute for some situations. If that is the start of an ongoing trend there's a good chance DwDg via service accounts could get deprecated. I hope that's not the case, but you never know.